# How to add timer between loop controllers being called in a single thread in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, jmeter-5.0

I added a jmx script in JMeter5.0 with two loop controllers called within a thread. two loop controllers are:

1. User login
2. User Logout

I want all my users from CSV to login at once and then logout at once, which is working fine, but before next login, I want some delay (after logout controller).

Putting constant timer will make the delay in all requests instead of loop controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that JMeter's [scoping rules] execute Timers **before** Samplers

> 2.Timers
>
> 3.Sampler

So either put Timer as a child of first sampler in Login Controller, (it'll add delay also in first login)

Or add a  [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) at the end of the Logout controller with Timer as its child

> it allows pauses to be included without needing to generate a sample. For variable delays, set the pause time to zero, and add a Timer as a child.

Comment: This worked with Flow Control Action having pause time 0 and constant timer as its child. But instead of adding in the end of Logout Controller since it is a Loop controller, added it after the module controller call in the thread. Thanks!